# grails: counting string size using execute query

Tags: grails, groovy, hql, executequery

I just want to know it is possible to convert this line of codes in a single execute Query in Grails.

```
String answer = StudentAnswerData.findWhere(student: studentObject, exam: examObject)?.answer

answer.replaceAll('0','')?.size()
```

The code queries for a specific **StudentAnswerData** then counts the characters of its answer which are not *zero* where **answer** is a String composed of numeric characters (**e.g.** *2435000025442032030000* ).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aside from doing some database specific SQL there isn't anything in Grails or GORM that will accomplish this.

Comment: `answer.replaceAll('','0')` will add a '0' before, after and between each character! is that a typo?

Comment: Looks like the OP meant to write `answer.replaceAll('0','')`, based on the question.

Comment: You might be able to add a method to your domain class that computes the counts and then call that method?

Comment: im sorry, that's a typo @nickdos. Yes I can create a method for that, but I'm just wondering if I can also do this in HQL using StudentAnswerData.executeQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Derived Properties

http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties

```
class StudentAnswerData {
    Integer answerLength
    String answer

    static mapping = {
        answerLength formula: "length(replace(answer, '0', ''))"  //oracle specific syntax
    }
}
```

Then you can use answerLength as a regular attribute